# Is there a way to include and execute same directory in one pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have one azure pipeline with two different stages.

The problem is, i have to include one directory for one stage and exclude the same directory for another stage. I need only one pipeline and I am trying to solve it it somehow.
Is there any ways of solving this ? Maybe some other technics ?

Thanks in response.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to include and execute same directory in one pipeline?

The folder is the default git checkout location for Azure pipelines.

[Checkout path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path)

There no way to include and execute the directory.

But, you could use the copy task to move and delete the folder out of the folder if needed:

[Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

[Delete Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Hmm, i will try, will update if something happen :)

Comment: @kahaboom, Sure, looking forward to your reply.

Comment: thanks, it helped
sorry for late response